# HTML Text Field Math / Displaying Answer in Text Field

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield

I don't have much experience with HTML or javascript coding and I am trying to make a simple calculation app. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#p1 {
     float:left;
     padding:5px 150px;

}
#h1 {
     float:left;
     padding:5px 150px;

}
#v1 {
     float:left;
     padding:5px 150px;

}
#p2 {
     padding:5px 150px;

}
#h2  {
     padding:5px 150px;

}
#v2 {
     padding:5px 150px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><center><b>Bernoulli's Energy Balance</b></center></h1>

<center><h2>P<sub>1</sub> + &rho;*g*h<sub>1</sub> + &rho;*(<sup>V<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup></sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>) = P<sub>2</sub> + &rho;*g*h<sub>2</sub> + &rho;*(<sup>V<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup></sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>) + &rho;*F</h2></center>

<form name="boxes" action="">

<div id="p1" name="p1">
P<sub>1</sub>:<input type="text" name="P1" size=3></div>

<div id="p2" name="p2" align="right">
P<sub>2</sub>:<input type="text" name="P2" size=3><br></div><br>

<div id="h1" name="h1">
h<sub>1</sub>:<input type-"text" name="h1" size=3></div>

<div id="h2" name="h2" align="right">
h<sub>2</sub>:<input type-"text" name="h2" size=3></div><br>

<div id="v1" name="v1">
V<sub>1</sub>:<input type-"text" name="V1" size=3></div>

<div id="v2" name="v2" align="right">
V<sub>2</sub>:<input type-"text" name="V2" size=3></div><br>

<div id="rho" name="rho" align="center">
&rho;:<input type="text" name="rho" size=3></div><br>

<div id="F" name="F" align="center">
F:<input type="text" name="F" size=3></div><br>

<div id="g" name="g" align="center">
g:<input type="text" name="g" size=3 value="9.8"></div><br>

<input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Calculate">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function isEmpty(id) {
    var text = document,getElementById(id).value;
    if (!text.match(/\S/)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

function calculate(){

var p1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p1").value);
var p2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p2").value);
var h1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h1").value);
var h2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("h2").vaule);
var v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value);
var v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value);
var rho = parseInt(document.getElementById("rho").value);
var F = parseInt(document.getElementById("F").value);
var g = parseInt(document.getElementById("g").value);


var Lside = p1+(rho*g*h1)+(rho*((v1^2)/2));
var Rside = p2+(rho*g*h2)+(rho*((v2^2)/2))+(rho*F);
var ans = 0;

    if (isEmpty(p1)){
        ans = Rside-(rho*((v1^2)/2))-(rho*g*h1);
        document.getElementById("p1").value = ans.toString();
   }
    else if (isEmpty(h1)){
        ans = (Rside-(rho*((v1^2)/2))-p1)/(rho*g);
        document.getElementById("h1").value = ans.toString();
    }
    else if (isEmpty(v1)){
        ans = (Rside-p1-(rho*g*h1))/rho;
        ans = ans*2;
        ans = Math.sqrt(ans);
        document.getElementById("v1").value = ans.toString();
    }
    else if (isEmpty(p2)){
        ans = Lside-(rho*((v2^2)/2))-(rho*g*h2)-(rho*F);
        document.getElementById("p2").value = ans.toString();
    }
    else if (isEmpty(h2)){
        ans = (Lside-(rho*((v2^2)/2))-(rho*F)-p2)/(rho*g);
        document.getElementById("h2").value = ans.toString();

    }
}

</script>




</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do the calculations and have the answer displayed in a text box. If that cannot be done I have also tried to display the answer in a

tag but that did not work either.

Here is what the code looks like so far: http://jsfiddle.net/fCXMt/238/

It is supposed to find which text field is left blank and then do the calculation to find the value by using the other values which will all be given.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly went through your code, the id's assigned are assigned to the div's and not the input values themselves.You  are getting the wrong id's as from what i can see.

```
var p1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("p1").value);
```

should be

```
var p1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("P1").value);//notice the capital.
```

I also see that some divs that contain the input have id's but not the input fields themselves.

On line 76 you have a typo 
`var text = document,getElementById(id).value;`
it should be `document.getElementById(id).value;`

Comment: it still won't work as the form elements have no IDs in this instance only names. You are on the right track though. The HTML needs to be changed or the elements need to be referenced by name `document.forms[0].elements["P1"]`, or something like that. It has been so long since I have referenced a form element by name that I have forgotten how.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of errors. This is what it looks like after correcting the errors.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emtjhgx5/)

(For some reason, the first six inputs are unclickable on the fiddle. So, to get the focus on those inputs, click on the left top corner of the Result window and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1><center><b>Bernoulli's Energy Balance</b></center></h1>
  <center>
    <h2>P<sub>1</sub> + &rho;*g*h<sub>1</sub> + &rho;*(<sup>V<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup></sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>) = P<sub>2</sub> + &rho;*g*h<sub>2</sub> + &rho;*(<sup>V<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup></sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>) + &rho;*F</h2>
  </center>
  <br />
  <div class="data">
    <form>
      <div class="left">P<sub>1</sub>:
        <input id="p1" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="right">P<sub>2</sub>:
        <input id="p2" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="left">h<sub>1</sub>:
        <input id="h1" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="right">h<sub>2</sub>:
        <input id="h2" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="left">V<sub>1</sub>:
        <input id="v1" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="right">V<sub>2</sub>:
        <input id="v2" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <div class="center">&rho;:
        <input id="rho" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="center">F:
        <input id="F" type="text" size="3" />
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="center">g:
        <input id="g" type="text" size="3" value="9.8" />
      </div>
      <br />
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function calculate() {
  var p1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("p1").value, 10);
  var p2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("p2").value, 10);
  var h1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("h1").value, 10);
  var h2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("h2").vaule, 10);
  var v1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v1").value, 10);
  var v2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("v2").value, 10);
  var rho = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rho").value, 10);
  var F = parseFloat(document.getElementById("F").value, 10);
  var g = parseFloat(document.getElementById("g").value, 10);

  var Lside = p1 + (rho * g * h1) + (rho * ((v1 ^ 2) / 2));
  var Rside = p2 + (rho * g * h2) + (rho * ((v2 ^ 2) / 2)) + (rho * F);
  var ans;

  if (!p1) {
    ans = Rside - (rho * ((v1 ^ 2) / 2)) - (rho * g * h1);
    document.getElementById("p1").value = Math.round(ans * 100) / 100;
  } else if (!h1) {
    ans = (Rside - (rho * ((v1 ^ 2) / 2)) - p1) / (rho * g);
    document.getElementById("h1").value = Math.round(ans * 100) / 100;
  } else if (!v1) {
    ans = (Rside - p1 - (rho * g * h1)) / rho;
    ans = ans * 2;
    ans = Math.sqrt(ans);
    document.getElementById("v1").value = Math.round(ans * 100) / 100;
  } else if (!p2) {
    ans = Lside - (rho * ((v2 ^ 2) / 2)) - (rho * g * h2) - (rho * F);
    document.getElementById("p2").value = Math.round(ans * 100) / 100;
  } else if (!h2) {
    ans = (Lside - (rho * ((v2 ^ 2) / 2)) - (rho * F) - p2) / (rho * g);
    document.getElementById('h2').value = Math.round(ans * 100) / 100;
  }
}
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = calculate;
```

#### CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.data {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.left {
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: The `.right` div overlap the `.left` making any inputs in the `.right` un-clickable. `z-index` or better use off CSS for the layout would fix it (float or inline-block come to mind)